# How to set the ID3 Year on an mp3?

Tags: nautilus, rhythmbox, mp3, id3, eyed3

I'm creating my own MP3s with an online service, and I'm setting the "Year" attribute in the ID3v tag, but I'm having trouble getting it to work with both Nautilis and Rhythmbox. In Nautilis, when I click on "Properties" and select the "Audio" tab, it shows "Year: Unknown". In Rhythmbox, it does the same when selecting the file "Properties" and says it's "Unknown". When I use EasyTag though, it works fine and shows the Year field set properly. I've also tried using eyeD3 to try both ID3 v1.x, v2.3 and v2.4, but they all show "Unknown".

One other observation was when I changed the year from "Unknown" to "2013" in Rhythmbox, and then closed Rhythmbox, Nautilis still showed "Unknown" for the year.

Is there something more to setting the Year field on ID3 tags that I'm missing, or is this just some subtlety between how different programs interpret the tags?

Comment: May be you should set the Recording Date (TDRC) instead when using ID3v2.4 as suggested on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2_Frame_Specification_.28Version_2.4_.E2.80.93_delta_respect_to_2.3.29)

Answer (score 0):

Try the KDE MP3 ID3 tag editor.

With the KDE MP3 ID3 tag editor, you can edit tags of multiple files, e.g. the artist, album, year and genre of all files of an album typically have the same values and can be set together.<sup>[UA](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/kid3/)</sup>

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install kid3
```

Or just click [**KDE MP3 ID3 tag editor** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/kid3/)